# Do GCP or AWS support C++ and GUI app development?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, wxwidgets

I am interested in developing web apps using the following technologies on the cloud:

1) C++
2) A GUI tool that can be called from C++ (such as wxWidgets)

I have checked out **GCP** (Google Cloud Platform) and **AWS** for these 2 technologies.

In general, I have found that these 2 PaaS sites support the following technologies for developing web apps:Java, .NET, PHP, node.js, Python, Ruby, Go.

Therefore I'd like to ask if either of these PaaS sites supports **C++** development including **GUI apps** built using **C++**?

Comment: [AppStream](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) might be of interest if you're referring to running unmodified Qt apps and serving them to (thin) clients.

Comment: Portable C++ has no notion of GUI.

Comment: @MarcoA., does `AppStream` support `wt` (web toolkit) apps? (`wt` is a library which can be used to develop web apps using C++)

Comment: @Ron, I know that. However, third-party libraries (such as `wxwidgets`) can be used to develop GUI apps using C++.

Comment: @SSteven AppStream is a high performance desktop streaming service. You create your application and you stream it to clients or browsers (even hardware accelerated). You can use pretty much anything you like. Not sure if that's what you're searching for though.

Comment: @MarcoA., does GCP (or any other PaaS site) have a product similar to AppStream?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in solution but admittedly I've never used GCP.

Comment: @SSteven, you can actually use wxWidgets (latest), which has a wxWebView control. Check the documentation and the appropriate sample.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AWS myself but I can provide some insight on GCP.

In short, C++ is not supported on the native runtime environments provided on App Engine (which is the PaaS solution of GCP). You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802172) for more details on this.

However, there are some workarounds available you could try to see if those fit your needs. Firstly you could make use of the App Engine Flex custom runtime environments where you will be able to run in an environment defined by a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) which will allow you to use your own runtime environment. You can refer to [this quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) which goes over the steps required to use custom runtimes. Make sure that your C++ app that will reside inside the docker container works as a service that is up and running continuously serving incoming traffic through HTTP otherwise you might end up stumbling with the same problem described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/333).

Alternatively, I found [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/invoking-legacy-code) that goes over the steps to implement an architectural pattern for invoking legacy code on App Engine.